# Informatica BDM Access a Local Image

Tags: html, informatica

In Informatica BDM I have a java transformation that sends emails containing HTML formatting. At one point in my code I add an image via hyperlink and it works great, the problem is that the server I will be hosting this on has no direct internet access so I need to load this image locally. The trouble is that Informatica seems to have trouble importing images, even if I specify the path where the image is located. Any help in troubleshooting this is greatly appreciated.

Here is a snippet of my code, note that I am using the java activation framework and the javax.mail to send emails.

```java
 emaildescription = emaildescription.concat("<center><img   style=\"width:150px;height:100px;\" src=\"C:/Users/ya_boi/Pictures/companyLogo.png\" alt=\"CompanyLogo\" title=\"CompanyLogo\"></center><br><br>");
```

Comment: Can you provide a snippet of the part of your code that handles this interaction? It'd be difficult to point the exact issue without that information.

Comment: @Kurisu I have added the line that is giving me troubles, please let me know if anything is unclear.